# Excel date time find max / min and max min timespan

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date-time

I have data time data in excel in the format "04/18/2014 17:09:09". I would like to use MAX and MIN on a range of such dates to get max, min and time span between min-max.
I tried using custom format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" but thats hopeless - MAX always returns 01/00/1900 00:00:00.
What to do the be able to to time base caclulations on time stamps like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MAX() is returning *01/00/1900 00:00:00*

it means that MAX() is really returning **0**

This, in turn, means that your date/times are text rather than numerical values.

You need to convert then to "true" dates before they can be used in calculations.

**EDIT#1**

With data like yours in column **A** starting in **A1** , in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

and copy down

Then you can use you **MAX** and **MIN** against column **B** rather than **A**

Comment: OK but how to do that?

Comment: See my **EDIT#1** ........................